# Selecting the DataGridViewRow from a LINQ query [c#]

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, datatable

I have a data grid view and a datatable.
I'm performing a LINQ query on the data table, and I want to select the specific row that the LINQ query filtered. what is the best way to do so? 
thank you!

```
var emp = (from x in dtRoles.AsEnumerable()
            where x.Field<string>("ID")==txtEmp.Id
            select x).FirstOrDefault();

if (emp != null)
{
    //select the specific row in dgvRoles
}
```

Comment: You requirement is get a single row from `DataTable`?

Comment: yes, I am getting one row or null (FirstOrDefault)

Comment: The `Linq` you have used is correct but you can use `Lambda` or `DataTable.Select` (not converting into `Enumerable`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the row in `DataGridView`, you can simply change the query to search on `DataGridView.Rows`.

To do so, you can use `DataBoundItem` of `DataGridViewRow` which is the object which is showing in the row. In case you are using a `DataTable` as a data source of the control, the data-bound item will be `DataRowView`. So you can use such query:

```
var row = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(x=>!x.IsNewRow)
    .Where(x => ((DataRowView)x.DataBoundItem).Row.Field<string>("Id") == "1")
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (row != null)
    row.Selected = true;
```

If for any reason you want to start searching on `DataTable`, then first find the `DataRow`, then search between `Rows` of the `DataGridView` to find that row:

```
var item = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Id") == "1").FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
{
    var row = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(x => ((DataRowView)x.DataBoundItem).Row == item).FirstOrDefault();
    if (row != null)
        row.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: thank you! this was exactly what I was looking for
what do you think would be faster, using the LINQ query or a for-each loop?

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified by `FirstOrDefault` extension method. By using with `Lambda`, we can get the specific row.

```
var result = dtRoles.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("ID")== "Sample");//Returns a DataRow
```

Or, without converting the `DataTable` into `Enumerable` we can filter the specific row(s) using `DataTable.Select`. In this case the return type is a `DataTable`.

```
    var result = dtRoles.Select("ID = 'Sample'"); //Returns a dataTable
    var row = result[0];//Specific row
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDIKgP) For with sample data

Comment: the linq query works just fine. i just wanted to select the specific row in the data grid view